# How can I see all the threads while using reddit PRAW in order to get number of comments?

Tags: python, pandas, praw

I'm trying to get the number of comments from each Daily discussion in the Bitcoin markets subreddit, using the reddit Python API.
I run the code and it seems like it's randomly skipping posts, here is an example:

```
                                              title       num_comments
0          [Daily Discussion] Monday, July 27, 2020          1199
1        [Daily Discussion] Sunday, August 02, 2020           606
2      [Daily Discussion] Saturday, August 01, 2020           705
3          [Daily Discussion] Friday, July 31, 2020           451
4          [Daily Discussion] Sunday, July 26, 2020           515
```

Also I'm getting only 250 results, while trying to get 1000.
Here is my code:

```
posts[] 
markets = reddit.subreddit('BitcoinMarkets')
for post in markets.search('Daily_Discussion', limit=1000):
posts.append([post.title, post.num_comments])
posts = pd.DataFrame(posts,columns=['title', 'num_comments'])
posts.to_csv('cryptoreddit1.csv', index=False) 
print(posts)
```

Thanks to all the readers.

Comment: This Reddit post might prove useful: https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/aem6r3/getting_more_than_250_search_results_searchapipraw/
It seems like they limited the API response to 250 comments at one point.